# CasperJS download and save file to specific location

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to download and temporarily save a file  using casperjs.

```
casper.start("http://www.google.fr/", function() {

  var path = 'C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/logo.png';
  fs.write(path, this.download("http://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo3w.png"), 'w');
});
```

I've tried opening the file in photo viewer, and it reads 'photo viewer does not support the file format'

Comment: If you've read the documentation, you should have seen that [`casper.download`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) takes the source URL *and* the target file. You don't have to use `fs.write`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll review the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

Istead of fs.write, use:

`this.download("http://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo3w.png", path);`

Hope this helps.